# Upload de imagens com c# windows forms e php

Tags: php, c#, http, upload, ftp

Estou tentando encontrar uma solução para o meu problema a pelo menos duas semanas e não consigo fazer isso funcionar. A ideia é a seguinte, eu possuo uma aplicação `Windows Forms` escrita em `C#`, na qual eu terei um `OpenFileDialog` que irá selecionar o caminho para uma imagem **.png** ou **.jpg** no **computador do cliente**, e selecionado este caminho, quando eu clicar em gravar, a imagem precisa ser renomeada (*pode ser para data do dia*), e depois enviada para um serviço em `PHP` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload']))
    {
        //Pegando extensão do arquivo
        $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'],-4)); 

        $name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];

        $dir = './upload/'; //Diretório para uploads 

        //Fazer upload do arquivo
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir.$name); 
        echo("Imagen enviada com sucesso!");
    }
```

Basicamente a ideia é fazer upload de imagens usando `C#` (*a partir de uma aplicação `Windows Forms`*) do lado do cliente e enviar isso para o `PHP` (*ou então direto para o diretório de destino no servidor*).

O problema aqui é basicamente:

> Pegar a imagem `->` renomear da imagem `->` enviar para pasta `uploads` no servidor.

**Observação:** a imagem tem que ser renomeada antes de ser enviada para o servidor, uma vez que eu associo o nome estático da imagem à um registro no banco de dados para posteriormente buscar a imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient), enviando um `post` para o endereço do `script` [php](/questions/tagged/php), e [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.118).aspx) para enviar a foto ou arquivo qualquer para o servidor. Na configuração de nome eu coloquei a geração por [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) para não haver repetição de nome.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    System.Net.Http.StreamContent streamContent = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(
        System.IO.File.Open(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    );

    System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent form = 
        new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();

    form.Add(streamContent, "fileUpload", string.Format("{0}{1}",
                               Guid.NewGuid(),
                               System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)));

    System.Net.Http.HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();             
    http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
    var res = http.PostAsync("send.php", form)
        .Result.Content;

    string r = res.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    http.Dispose();
}
```

Esse código é um base, é funcional e pode ser alterado mediante suas regras de negócio.

<sup>**Observação:** No `script` [php](/questions/tagged/php) não fiz nenhuma alteração.</sup>

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Classe HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MultipartFormDataContent Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [StreamContent Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Método Guid.NewGuid ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado! Você me ajudou de mais com isso, obrigado mesmo!